# Additional image in bootstrap navbar

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I try to study a Bootstrap 3 last three months.
All fine, but I would like to put in my navbar the additional image (in right side of it).

In my opinion, to insert a picture directly in HTML code like:

picture
 - bad idea, and I created a  with a background picture, specified through CSS, but the picture does not appear on the page ...

How can I do it?
And possible whether to do it at all?

Comment: Need to show us some code

Comment: You need to post an actual example of **YOUR** code, the default bootstrap `navbar` isn't any help as there considerations such how are you planning on formatting your right positioned image on mobile viewports given that the `navbar-toggle` will be underneath it.  See [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Follow this guide
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image

To have an additional image on the other side of the menu, you just need to put it as part of the link menu. See example:

http://jsbin.com/mupobo/edit?html,output

Comment: @Heartless_forever see updated post with link to jsbin